# WebClient does not return a "valid" list of Strings

Tags: java, spring, list, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a spring boot app that among others, has an endpoint that when hit, returns a list of strings. I also have another spring boot app that hits the first app's endpoint to get the data. The fetch code:

```
return webClient.get().uri("/sensors/get-cities").headers(httpHeaders -> {
      httpHeaders.set("Authorization", auth);
    }).retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(String.class).collectList().block();
```

The above yields a list but with this format when I inspect it in the debbuger, `"["city"]"`. The outer double quotes, I get them because it's a string but the brackets and the inside double quotes, I do not. I tried replacing these characters but I had no luck with the brackets (tried regex). It is like they are not there, but at the same time they are. I am confused at this point. But I think that the behavior of the fetch code is not normal, it should yield a valid array of strings.

Comment: Since this very likely returns JSON a list of strings would be represented as `["string 1", "string 2", ...]`. And since JSON is a _text_ format your client gets a string that contains this JSON and which would need to be properly _parsed_ (not using regex though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably getting (im guessing here) is a response body that looks something like this:

```
[
    "New York",
    "Madrid",
    "London"
]
```

You then tell webflux that you want to convert the body to a `Flux` of `String` by calling `bodyToFlux(String.class)`.

So the framework takes the entire response and makes a string out of it

```
// A string of the entire array (im escaping the quotation marks)
"[\"New York\",\"Madrid\",\"London\"]"
```

And then the framework will throw the entire thing into a `Flux` which means it takes the first position in the `Flux`. You then emit all the values into a `List` by calling `collectList` The equivalent code is sort of:

```
List<String> oneString = Flux.just("[\"New York\",\"Madrid\",\"London\"]")
    .collectList()
    .block();
```

So you get a list, with one string in it, which is the entire body.

What you probably want to do is to get a list out if it. And this is one way to do it:

```
List<String> strings = webClient.get()
                          .uri("/sensors/get-cities")
                          .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                              httpHeaders.set("Authorization", auth);
                          })
                          .retrieve()
                          .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})
                          .block();
```

Spring explains `ParameterizedTypeReference`:

> The purpose of this class is to enable capturing and passing a generic Type. In order to capture the generic type and retain it at runtime

So its sort of a class that makes sure we can use generic types like `List<T>` and helps us with type information.

So what we do is that we now take the response and tell the framework that the body is a list of strings directly. We dont need to do `collectList` anymore as the framework will stick it in a list for us. We then call `block` to wait in the response.

Answer (score 2):

Your Springboot API returns result as parsed to JSON (this is default behavior). So it first builds a list of Strings (in your case just a single String `"city"` and than serializes it to Json. In this case since it is a list it serializes it to JSON array as opposed to JSON Object. Read about JSON [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). So in your second Springboot app that hits the API from the first one should assume that you are getting JSON which you need to parse to get your list. To parse it you can use [readValue()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) method of `ObjectMapper` class of Json Jackson library which is a default JSON library in Springboot. your code would be

```
List<String> myList;
ObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//Add setters for ObjectMapper configuration here if you want a specific config
try {
  myList = objectMapper.readValue(myJsonString, List.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
...
}
```

In addition I wrote my own Open-source library called MgntUtils, that includes `JsonUtils` class which is a thin wrapper over Json Jackson library. It provides just Json parser and serializer, but in many cases that is all you need. With my library you would only need one dependency as oppose to Jackson, and `JsonUtils` class just have 4 methods, so by far easier to understand. But in your case if you use my library the code would be very similar to the above code. It would be something like this:

```
List<String> myList;
try {
  myList = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(myJsonString, List.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
...
}
```

Note that in this case you won't have to instantiate and configure `ObjectMapper` instance as `readObjectFromJsonString` is a static method. Anyway if you are interested in using my library you can find maven artifacts [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and The library itself with source code and javadoc is on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Javadoc for `JsonUtils` class is [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html)

Comment: the library proposed pulls in its own version of jackson which in turn might conflict with the version used by spring which also in turn might cause a version missmatch with possible classnotfound exceptions, or methodnotfound exceptions because maven might pick the wrong version during compile time. This library may be good to use with standalone java applications, i would not recommend the usage with for instance webflux or a regular spring boot application. If this library is to be used, a spring starter should be written that pulls in the version number from the spring parent.

Comment: @Toerktumlare while your concerns are legitimate, every single one of them is resolved by very simple, standard and strait forward way. When you add my library maven artifact to a project that already have jackson library just add exclude for jackson artifacts for MgntUtils library. (I have done it multiple times and it works perfectly). On the other hand MgntUtils library needs to have jackson in case it is used in the projects that didn't utilize jackson. Also, since Jackson is backward compatible, and you see that MgntUtils uses newer version of jackson you can (see next comment)

Comment: exclude it from other sources and rely on the version brought my MgntUtils lib. (I have done so and it works fine). And finally probably the most compelling and convincing argument - this library has been used in real life hi-load hi-security production applications. Here is just incomplete list of the companies where I personally integrated this library  into their production applications: Motorola, Elbit, Celebrite, ZoomInfo and some others that I can not name due to contractual obligations. In each of those companies this library passed rigorous security checks  (see next comment)

Comment: prior to being included in their code. Also, this library gets between 2 to 4 thousand downloads monthly. (by far not the biggest but still significant). So, I can with the highest degree of confidence say that this library works seamlessly in Sprig boot environment and I highly recommend it for use both as stand alone and within Spring boot or any other enviroment

Comment: What other does or does not is out of my concern, jus because many use it it does not legitimise it. Im pointing out legit concerns and i would not recommend people to use it. I would recommend you write a spring starter that pulls in the version from the parent as in its current use it might give unpredictable versioning and might produce security issues as you will not be sure what version of jackson the application is running.

Comment: `”When you add my library maven artifact to a project that already have jackson library just add exclude for jackson artifacts for MgntUtils library.”` that is a workaround to make your library work. If you dont do that you might get unexpected behaviours. With security issues if there is version missmatching. Still would not recommend. As for the companies, its up to them what security risks they want to take. Would not pass the classified systems i work on.

Comment: As for all the companies you mentioned, they are all companies you worked for, so yeah… i’ll leave at that

Comment: @Toerktumlare Here is the point were we strongly disagree. Excluding jackson from my library. We both agree that it will work but you think it is a workaround and I believe it is a very standard solution and not workaround at all. Think about it: obviously I can not provide the library without jackson in it as it wouldn't be working in the project that doesn't gave jackson. But for the project that does one can simply exclude unwanted versions. Anyway, if I don't convince you its OK, obviously, both of us are entitled for our opinions.